# Is there a way to map a function over sections of a 2d array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy array, on the order of N x 4000 x 4000 and I would like to operate on this array in chunk sizes of 4000 x 100 in order to do some data processing.

I would like to do something like:

```
def my_op(section):
     # operate on 4000 x 100 section
     return section.mean() - section

new_array = large_array.map(my_op, chunksize=(4000,100))
```

So far I can accomplish what I need to on 4000 x 4000 sized sections using a for loop but it feels inefficient.

```
def op_2d(large_array):
    # operate on 4000 x 4000 values here
    # each 4000 x 100 section is treated differently based on their average
    shape = large_array.shape
    ndim = large_array.ndim
    vals_per_segment = 100
    nsegments = int(shape[-1] / vals_per_segment)
    nrows = shape[0]
    
    # my complicated reshaping operations to create a copy of the array with
    # the values I want to subtract in shape of (N x 4000 x 100 segment)
    segment_order = large_array.reshape((nrows, nsegments, vals_per_segment))

    # average every segment
    segment_averages = segment_order.mean(axis=(0, ndim))
    
    # create a value by value copy with the values I want to subtract
    correction = segment_averages.repeat(vals_per_segment).reshape(nsegments, vals_per_segment)
    out = (correction - segment_order).reshape(shape)
    
    return out

# using a for loop
for i in range(large_array.shape[0]):
    large_array[i, :, :] = op_2d(large_array[i, :, :])
```

In this particular case it would clean up the code a lot. It wasn't clear to me that map, nditer, or vectorize would do the job, but I feel like it could possibly use less memory or de-clutter the code if I were to use one of these functions.

Please let me know if my idea is misguided and there is no advantage to this.

Comment: If you must work with chunks of `large_array`, that iteration is as good as any.  `reshape` does not (normally) make a copy, so it quite efficient.  `map`, `nditer`, `vectorize` don't improve either the time or memory use; they may even be worse.

Comment: I was sort of getting that sense too from reading around stackoverflow. Being able to do something like ‘new_array = large_array.map(my_op, chunksize=(4000,100))’ would be so much more concise than what I’m doing. And I end up doing lots of operations like this in the type of analysis I do.